# Problema ao remover readonly no Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Tenho uma função que remove o `readonly` de um campo após focar o mesmo:
`$input.removeAttr('readonly');`

O problema é que apenas no Internet Explorer mesmo após remover o readonly ele não me permite digitar no campo. O problema só resolve se eu sair do campo e focá-lo novamente. Gostaria de uma solução em que não tivesse que utilizar o evento `blur` e `focus`, pois tenho outros comportamentos envolvendo a função `blur`.

Comment: Você já tentou utilizar o disabled do input ? Exemplo do fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fvtgmxv7/2/

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o erro no IE 11.0, mais tente `$input.prop('readonly',false)`, [Veja aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/9050m0La/)

Comment: @abfurlan o problema ocorre caso o foco já esteja no campo e dinamicamente seja removido o efeito. O simples fato de clicar no campo já resolve o problema

Comment: @abfurlan isso: http://jsfiddle.net/9050m0La/3/

Comment: tente usar o [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute): http://jsfiddle.net/h5jfhbk4/6/

Answer (score 0):

Deves usar `$input.prop('readonly', false);`

Usa [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) em vez de [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) pois o `readonly` é uma propriedade nativa do elemento e o seu estado é setado e lido via `.prop()`.

Comment: mesmo com `.prop` continua com o mesmo problema

Comment: @RubyDevJunior faz um jsFiddle que reproduza o problema, diz qual é a versão do IE e coloca aqui que eu dou uma olhada.

Comment: segue http://jsfiddle.net/h5jfhbk4/6/ estou usando o IE 12, para simular ao rodar clique no campo e tente digitar. Em outros navegadores libera a digitação após os 3 segundos, no IE não, é necessário clicar novamente no campo @Sergio